# angular ui select2, bind data undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ui-select, angular-ui-select

I use angular-ui-select2.

```
            <select ui-select2 ng-model="vm.salonStaffModel.type">
                <option ng-repeat="occ in vm.categoriesType" value="{{occ.key}}">
                    {{occ.key}}</option>
            </select>
```

I bind data to vm.salonStaffModel.type successfully, when I select value from dropdown list. But when I refresh page, the value is undefined, although vm.salonStaffModel.type has value, which I have selected before. Thanks!

[image]

This is my controller

```js
export default class SalonStaffCreateCtrl {
  constructor($state, SalonStaff, SalonListService, popUpMessageService) {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.popUpMessageService = popUpMessageService;
    this.salonListService = SalonListService;
    this.salonStaffModel = {
      type:"AUS"
    };
    this.SalonStaff = SalonStaff;
    this.state = $state;
    this.yesNoLazylist = [{ "key": false, "group": null }, { "key": true, "group": null }];
    this.categoriesType = [{"key":"AUS","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:259"},{"key":"BD","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:260"},{"key":"735","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:261"},{"key":"713","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:262"},{"key":"714","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:263"},{"key":"IND","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:264"},{"key":"734","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:265"},{"key":"711","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:266"},{"key":"716","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:267"},{"key":"731","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:268"},{"key":"BUR","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:269"},{"key":"NZ","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:270"},{"key":"PK","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:271"},{"key":"733","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:272"},{"key":"SGP","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:273"},{"key":"717","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:274"},{"key":"T","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:275"},{"key":"USA","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:276"},{"key":"725","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:277"}];
    this.categoriesService = [];
    this.getServiceSalon();
  }

}

SalonStaffCreateCtrl.$inject = ['$state', 'SalonStaff', 'SalonListService', 'popUpMessageService'];
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Type *</label>
                            <select ui-select2 ng-model="vm.salonStaffModel.type">
                    <option ng-repeat="occ in vm.categoriesType" value="{{occ.key}}">
                        {{occ.key}}</option>
                </select>
            
            <p ng-show="frm.type.$error.required && vm.submitted" class="red-text error-label-dropdown">Mandatory field(s)</p>
          </div>
```

Comment: vm.categoriesType  = [{"key":"AUS","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:259"},{"key":"BD","group":null,"$$hashKey":"object:260"}]

Comment: Provide JS fiddle or add code for your module and controller.

Comment: @AKA I have updated your request. I use Controller as not scope.